# Can Route model observe applicationController props?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building ember app, and I have date selector at the top and a few tabs. Each tab represents a model to work with, but all models need date selector. So I store the date selector values as `applicationController` properties, and I've reached the point where I need to load data with `store.query("Model", {date: applicationController.date})` and now I'm lost. If I use ModelController with hooks like:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    appController: Ember.inject.controller('application'),
    myNeedData: function() {
        this.store.findAll('myNeedData',
             {date: this.get('appController').get('selectedUrlDate')}
        );
    }.property('appController.selectedUrlDate')
})
```

everything actually works, but it is a hack. So I need to load model data through Route's `model()`. But how can I pass `applicationController` property to Route and make it observe the changes?

Comment: You should use a service

Comment: Thanks for response. Should I use service in controller then, and just leave a blank Route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, [Kitler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401094/kitler) for pointing out the path of researching. So I've made the service

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),

    loadModel(date) {
        // some important actions
    }
});
```

then the controller functions:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    nextMonth() {
        var date = this.get('selectedDate');
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
        this.set('selectedDate', new Date(date));
    },
    prevMonth() {
        var date = this.get('selectedDate');
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
        this.set('selectedDate', new Date(date));
    },
});
```

and the route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    modelService: Ember.inject.service('my-service'),

    model() {
        return this.prepareModel();
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    },
    prepareModel() {
        const date = this.controllerFor('application').get('selectedUrlDate');
        return this.get('modelService').loadModel(date);
    },

    actions: {
        nextMonth() {
            const self = this;
            self.controllerFor('application').nextMonth();
            self.refresh();
        },
        prevMonth() {
            const self = this;
            self.controllerFor('application').prevMonth();
            self.refresh();
        },
    }
});
```

So now I have data manipulation in route, not important repeatable property `currentDate` and its manipulation in application controller, and route accordingly changes model on user interactions due to `refresh`!